# Javascript show only if checkbox has a value?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm running an ajax script that needs to check a list of checkboxs to determine

1. Is a checkbox checked
2. Does it have a value
3. Pass the value to a function file

My struggle is that if nothing has been selected the value being passed is "". When the function file gets a value with nothing in it, it can't find a match and return anything.

In order to solve this I either need to pass a null status to the file or first check to see if an item is selected before I process this portion of the script.

I'm using the following script to do this. However it does not recognize when an item has been checked.

**Script:**

```
if(document.getElementsByName('category').checked) {
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('category');
var category = "";
    for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
    {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
        {
            category += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (category) category = category.substring(1);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="col-12">
       <label class="h6 my-3 pr-0" id="audience" for="language">Audiences</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="26" value="adult">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="26">Adult</label>
        </div><div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="28" value="children">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="28">Children</label>
        </div><div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="27" value="teen">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="27">Teen</label>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-accent mb-3 mt-3 mb-0 ajax" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
```

Question:

How do I either check the box has been selected before processing or pass a null value if nothing has been checked?

Comment: First thing I notice is you have `var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('category');`. Shouldn't this be getting "audience" instead of "category"?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have to checkbox sections one is category one is the audience. I just copied the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to attach an event listener by calling `addEventListener()`. Listen to the `change` event to detect the ticking/unticking of the checkbox.

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector(
  'input[name= category]'
);
checkbox.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // insert your function
  console.log(event)
});
```

Comment: The name of category is surely incorrect, that's the main mistake of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a submit button to activate your script. That way you can click all the checkboxes first and then submit

```
<form id="myForm">
 <div class="col-12">
       <label class="h6 my-3 pr-0" id="audience" for="language">Audiences</label>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="26" value="adult">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="26">Adult</label>
        </div><div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="28" value="children">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="28">Children</label>
        </div><div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="audience" type="checkbox" id="27" value="teen">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="27">Teen</label>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-accent mb-3 mt-3 mb-0 ajax" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myScript(); // call your javascript here
});
</script>
```

Comment: The question was about preparing the data to send it via AJAX. The op might be learning AJAX, in which case an answer not coping with it might be unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('category')
```

will return you a `NodeList` of the elements having the name of `category`. Since there are no such elements, it will return an empty `NodeList`. Now, you have an `if` where you check

```
document.getElementsByName('category').checked
```

but your NodeList has no `checked` attribute defined, so the result is `undefined`, which is a falsy value, so the `if` will be evaluated to `false`, therefore your code inside the `if` will never be executed. So, you will need to get the elements having the tag name of `audience`:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('audience');
```

Then traverse the checkboxes and collect the values:

```
var categories = [];
for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked) categories.push(checkbox.value);
}
category = categories.join(",");
```

This is the logic you will need to execute when you intend to calculate the category. Try it out in the browser console and check in and out the checkboxes before you do so.